# memcached bytes is larger than limit_maxbytes

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

In my opinion,`bytes` refers to the space memcached used now, and `limit_maxbytes` is the max space memcached can use. When I insert items into memcached constantly with `expiration=0`, the older item should replace the last recently used one by memcached's LRU algorithm. But the fact is, after constantly inseration, the `bytes` is larger than `limit_maxbytes` (with `evictions` increased). I wonder if now the actual occupied space is larger than `limit_maxbytes`? Or why `bytes` is larger than `limit_maxbytes`?  Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug, `limit_maxbytes` comes as KB not Byte.

I set max cache size `CACHESIZE="5GB"`, and stats shows only `5MB`.